# "Return to message list" hover icon is weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

In Careers, when you view a message  there is "Return to message list" icon that normally looks like this:

[image]

When hovered, it becomes this:

[image]

Looks like a bug to me. Chrome 31.0.1650.63 but don't think it's browser specific.

Comment: This is my fault, but apparently I don't know CSS well enough to fix it, so our designer is cleaning this up.

Comment: Jin for the rescue! ;)

Comment: @NickLarsen oh, that's really cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is fixed now @ShadowWizard. Just a case of some new CSS selectors overriding some previous ones.

Comment: Nice, I also see you added `cursor:not-allowed` over the submit button when disabled, don't remember it was there before. :)